# Query creating an identifier for each packet

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sorry the title is not very descriptive but it is a tricky problem to word.

I have some data, about 200 or more rows of it, and each row has a PacketID, so several rows belong in the same packet. What I need to do, is convert all the PacketIDs from (Example - BDFD-2) to just a number (Example - 1) so all the entries with a packet identifier x need to have a packet identifier of say 3. Is there an SQL query that can do this? Or do I just have to go through manually.

Comment: Just a simple excel one imported into access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked about a query.  I wrote a quick VBA procedure instead just because it was so easy.  But I'm unsure whether it is appropriate for your situation.

I created tblPackets with a numeric column for new_PacketID.  I hoped that will make it clearer to see what's going on.  If you truly need to replace PacketID with the new number, you can alter the procedure to store `CStr(lngPacketID)` to that text field.  So this is the sample data I started with:

```
PacketID new_PacketID packet_data
BDFD-2                a
R2D2-22               aa
BDFD-2                b
R2D2-22               bb
EMC2-0                aaa
EMC2-0                bbb
```

And this is the table after running the procedure.

```
PacketID new_PacketID packet_data
BDFD-2              1 a
R2D2-22             3 aa
BDFD-2              1 b
R2D2-22             3 bb
EMC2-0              2 aaa
EMC2-0              2 bbb
```

And the code ...

```
Public Sub RenumberPacketIDs()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngPacketID As Long
    Dim strLastPacketID As String
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "SELECT PacketID, new_PacketID" & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM tblPackets" & vbCrLf & _
        "ORDER BY PacketID;"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)

    With rs
        Do While Not .EOF
            If !PacketID <> strLastPacketID Then
                lngPacketID = lngPacketID + 1
                strLastPacketID = !PacketID
            End If
            .Edit
            !new_PacketID = lngPacketID
            .Update
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

I think an approach like that could be fine for a one-time conversion.  However if this is an operation you need to perform repeatedly, it could be more complicated ... especially if you need each PacketID replaced with the same number from one run to the next ... eg. BDFD-2 was replaced by 1 the first time, so must be replaced by 1 every time you run the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few packet IDs, you can just use update:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET PacketID = 
       (
           CASE PacketID
               WHEN 'BDFD-2' THEN 3
               WHEN 'ABCD-1' THEN 5
               ELSE 2
           END
       )
```

The `ELSE` is optional.

Comment: Is there some logical conversion that needs applying? If so, what? Eg. do you need to convert `AAAA-1` into `2`, where `AAAA-` can be discarded, and `1` gets incremented?

Comment: No, the packetID's are randomly generated, I was thinking i needed somthing that would go though, check if this entry is the same as the last, if it is then make it x, and if it isn't than incriment x by i and then make it that. Except i don't know enough SQL to code that

Comment: Just go into the pretty-view of Access, order by PacketID and fly down the column making changes (enter to drop down 1 row and stay in same column). You'll be done in no time.

Comment: Yeah, i've done that now, took me about 20 minutes, i'm just worried about the possiblility of human error, which could reeeaallyly screw some important things up in this case

Comment: This is TSQL, for SQL Server and cannot be used in Access.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you even want to convert the packet ids to a number, they seem perfectly fine as they are. You could create a table of packets as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableOfRows.Packet_id AS PacketId INTO Packets FROM TableOfRows;
```

You can then use this to select the packet you are interested in and display the corresponding rows

Comment: Yes, except i need to put the data from this client into the same format as the data from every other client so it can be entered into the system, and the packetID's for every other client is a simple number